# Why can't windbg access network drive?

Tags: windows, windbg, remote-debugging, unc

I am trying to analyze a crash dump on my test machine, which has my working drive (source code and output) on my development machine mapped to the p: drive.

What is causing windbg to not be able to load symbols from my p: drive?

```
kd> !sym noisy
kd> .sympath P:\path\to\pdb
kd> .reload myDriver.sys
Warning: This Network path won't be validated (invalid UNC path): 'P:\path\to\pdb
... snip ...
kd> .reload -f myDriver.sys
... snip ...
... the usual warnings and errors about how it can't find stuff ...
************* Symbol Loading Error Summary **************
Module name            Error
myDriver               All symbol search paths were invalid
                Please check your symbol search path.


The following location did not respond and were excluded during symbol loading:
p:\path\to\pdb
Warning: This Network path won't be validated (invalid UNC path): 'P:\path\to\pdb
... snip ...
```

I can access `P:\path\to\pdb` from the cmd prompt and from Explorer. In admin and non-admin modes.

Comment: Do you use an old Windbg ?
I use 6.2.9200.20512 X86, and here it works
"Loaded pdb is y:\release\zzzProtocol.pdb"

Comment: Agree, I use 6.2.9200.16384.AMD64 and have never had a problem accessing anything across the network.